# Items keep adding to Listview when switching between fragments using a drop down menu

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am using ActionBarSherlock following the code from these two tutorial's: 
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-search-collapsible-view-in-android/ & http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/actionbarsherlock-custom-menu-list-navigation-fragments/

The issue that I'm having is that everytime I switch fragments using the drop down menu, the same data is being added to the listview and keeps adding per switch. The same thing also happens when the data from the listview is clicked to open up the SingleItemView and then I go back to the listview. Appriciate any help anybody can give.

**NOTE**: I have a search function and a button within the actionbar as well that is unrelated.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
// Declare Variables
NavListAdapter adapter;
EditText editsearch;
String[] title;
String[] subtitle;
Fragment fragment1 = new FiveHundred();
Fragment fragment2 = new OneThousand();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Generate title
    title = new String[] { "Title Fragment 1", "Title Fragment 2" };

    // Generate subtitle
    subtitle = new String[] { "Subtitle Fragment 1", "Subtitle Fragment 2" };


    // Pass results to NavListAdapter Class
    adapter = new NavListAdapter(this, title, subtitle);

    // Hide the ActionBar Title
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Create the Navigation List in your ActionBar
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // Listen to navigation list clicks
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navlistener = new OnNavigationListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            // Locate Position
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1);
                break;
            case 1:
                ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment2);
                break;
            }
            ft.commit();
            return true;
        }

    };
    // Set the NavListAdapter into the ActionBar Navigation
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navlistener);
}

// Create the options menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Get the options menu view from menu.xml in menu folder
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_layout, menu);

    // Locate the EditText in menu.xml
    editsearch = (EditText) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();

    // Capture Text in EditText
    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    // Show the search menu item in menu.xml
    MenuItem menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

    menuSearch.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

        // Menu Action Collapse
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Empty EditText to remove text filtering
            editsearch.setText("");
            editsearch.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        // Menu Action Expand
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Focus on EditText
            editsearch.requestFocus();

            // Force the keyboard to show on EditText focus
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Show the settings menu item in menu.xml
    MenuItem menuSettings = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings);

    // Capture menu item clicks
    menuSettings.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Do something here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing here!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

    });

    return true;
}

// EditText TextWatcher
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
                .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        adapter.filter(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Populate> populatelist = null;
private ArrayList<Populate> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Populate> populatelist) 
{
    mContext = context;
    this.populatelist = populatelist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Populate>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(populatelist);
}

public class ViewHolder 
{
    TextView Name;
    TextView Value;

}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return populatelist.size();
}

@Override
public Populate getItem(int position) 
{
    return populatelist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
} 

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        holder.Value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Value);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else 
    {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.Name.setText(populatelist.get(position).getName());
    holder.Value.setText(populatelist.get(position).getValue());     

    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass all data errorName
            intent.putExtra("Name",(populatelist.get(position).getName()));
            // Pass all data errorCode
            intent.putExtra("Value",(populatelist.get(position).getValue()));
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    return convertView;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) 
{
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    populatelist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) 
    {
        populatelist.addAll(arraylist);
    }
    else
    {
        for (Populate p : arraylist)
        {
            // Search filter code
            if (p.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
            {
                populatelist.add(p);
            }
            else if (p.getValue().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
            {
                populatelist.add(p);
            }
        }

    }       
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

NavListAdapter.java

```
public class NavListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
String[] mTitle;
String[] mSubTitle;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public NavListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] subtitle) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTitle.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mTitle[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtSubTitle;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_list_item, parent, false);

    // Locate the TextViews in nav_list_item.xml
    txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

    // Set the results into TextViews
    txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);
    txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtSubTitle;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dropdownView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_dropdown_item, parent,
            false);

    // Locate the TextViews in nav_dropdown_item.xml
    txtTitle = (TextView) dropdownView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtSubTitle = (TextView) dropdownView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

    // Set the results into TextViews
    txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);
    txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);

    return dropdownView;
}

public void filter(String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Populate.java

```
public class Populate 
{
private String Name;
private String Value;

public Populate(String Name, String Value) 
{
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Value = Value;
}

public String getName() 
{
    return this.Name;
}

public String getValue() 
{
    return this.Value;
}


}
```

SingleItemView.java

```
public class SingleItemView extends SherlockActivity
{
// Declare Variables
TextView txtName;
TextView txtValue;

String Name;
String Value;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);
    // Hide the keyboard
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);

    // Retrieve data from **Numbers**.java on item click event
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the results of Name
    Name = i.getStringExtra("Name");
    // Get the results of Value
    Value = i.getStringExtra("Value");


    // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    txtValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Value);


    // Load the results into the TextViews
    txtName.setText(Name);
    txtValue.setText(Value);

}

}
```

FiveHunded.java & OneThousand.java ---Both fragments essentially have the same code, but the data strings say different things.

```
public class FiveHundred extends SherlockFragment
{
// Declare Variables
ListView list;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
EditText editsearch;
String[] Name;
String[] Value;

ArrayList<Populate> arraylist = new ArrayList<Populate>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_main, container, false);
     return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    // Generate sample data
    Name = new String[] 
            { 
                // 0-10
                "A name goes here!!" 
            };

    Value = new String[] 
            { 
                // 0-10
                "A value goes here!!"
            };


    // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
    list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

    for (int i = 0; i < Name.length; i++)
    {
        Populate p = new Populate(Name[i], Value[i]);
        // Binds all Strings into an array
        arraylist.add(p);
    }

    // Pass results to ListViewAdapter.class
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

    // Binds the adapter to the ListView
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your problem is in the `FiveHunded` and `OneThousand` classes. You do not clean `ArrayList` when `OnStart` method is calling, so every time you switch fragments data is added to it and adapter gets ArrayList of bigger size.

Just add `arrayList.clear()` in `OnStart` method before your initializing loop.